# Flexbox grid with 7 columns

Tags: tailwind-css, flexboxgrid

I am creating a grid with tailwind and flexbox. Is it possible to create a 7 column grid? I know I can use width percentage but what would be the best practice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the best solution would be to use CSS Grid instead Flexboxes to do this. Tailwind supports grid with up to 12 columns by default ([docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns)).

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-7">
  <div class="col-span-1">1</div>
  <div class="col-span-3">2</div>
  <div class="col-span-3">3</div>
</div>
```

### If You really need to use flex:

By default there are classes `w-1/2`, `w-1/3`, `w-1/12` etc but not `w-1/7`. We can set width for div manually in style="" or CSS, but the best practice would be to extend Tailwind configuration.

We need to add to `tailwind.config.js` new width classes ([docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width#customizing)):

```
  module.exports = {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        width: {
+         '1/7': '14.2857143%',
+         '2/7': '28.5714286%',
+         '3/7': '42.8571429%',
+         '4/7': '57.1428571%',
+         '5/7': '71.4285714%',
+         '6/7': '85.7142857%',
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Now we can use our x/7 columns:

```
<div class="flex">
   <div class="w-1/7">1</div>
   <div class="w-3/7">2</div>
   <div class="w-3/7">3</div>
</div>
```

If You only want to get 7 columns with equal width, then we do not need to extend config and use width classes at all:

```
<div class="flex">
   <div class="flex-1">1</div>
   <!-- ... -->
   <div class="flex-1">7</div>
</div>
```